# Remove element not working in leetcode but works in VS

Tags: c#, arrays, list, algorithm, element

To be brief, I am working on a solution for leetcode question 27, Remove Element. It didn't work when I ran it, the values were completely wrong, but I am really confused as to why it wouldn't, so I tested it in VS and it works completely fine there. Really confusing.

The task:

> Given an integer array nums and an integer val, remove all occurrences of val in nums in-place. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val.
>
> Consider the number of elements in nums which are not equal to val be k, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:
>
> Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain the elements which are not equal to val. The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size of nums.
> Return k.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
    public class Leet
    {
        static public int LeetCode(int[] nums, int val)
        {
            int k;
            List<int> list = new();
            foreach (var number in nums)
            {
                if (number != val)
                {
                    list.Add(number);
                }
            }
            k = list.Count();
            return k;
        }
    }
```

I copied the same test input, an array containing [3,2,2,3] as `num` and `val` being 3. In VS, the output is [2,2]. In leetcode, it's returning [3,2].

What's going on? Really confused.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio. I accidentally put VSM as a mistype.

Comment: Looking at LeetCode's problem 27, it seems that you should update the values in `nums` such that the first `k` items are the items you're keeping, and then don't worry about the rest. At the moment you aren't changing the contents of `nums` at all.

Comment: I've copied in the LeetCode problem description for you.

Comment: Oh alright, thank you! Apologies to make you go to the website and look manually, I should have copied it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are asked to *modify* the array

> **Change** the array `nums` such that the first `k` elements of `nums` ...

and you don't do it; you've completed the task *partially* since you are returning `k`.
LeetCode expects someting like this:

```
static public int LeetCode(int[] nums, int val) {
  int result = 0; 

  for (int left = 0, right = 0; right < nums.Length; ++right) 
    if (nums[right] != val) {
      result += 1;

      nums[left++] = nums[right];
    }
  
  return result;
}
```

Please, note *inplace* condition: even if it's not tested (and you can declare `List<int>` and get all tests passed) you should not do it.

Time Complexity: `O(n)` Space complexity: `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Very nice explanation, Dmitry.
I did it like this (very similar to yours, but without two variables declared in the for)

```
 public int RemoveElement(int[] nums, int val)
 {
     int k = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
     {
         if (nums[i] != val)
         {
             nums[k++] = nums[i];
         }
     }
   
     return k;
 }
```